# Fail to adding an element into std::map by insert fucntion

Tags: c++

Here is my code snippets:

```
class khaos_event
{
public:
  khaos_event(){};
  ~khaos_event(){};
public:
  bool wait(uint32_t timeout){
    std::chrono::milliseconds millis{timeout};
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);
    return m_cv.wait_for(lock, millis) == std::cv_status::no_timeout;
  };
  void notify(void){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex>lock(m_mtx);
    m_cv.notify_one();
  };
private:
  std::condition_variable m_cv;
  std::mutex m_mtx;
};

int main()
{
  std::map<uint32_t, khaos_event> events;
  events.insert(std::make_pair(1, khaos_event()));
  ...
}
```

I was using the c++17 to compile this code. and get the following error message:

**error: no matching function for call to 'std::map<unsigned int, khaos_event>::insert(std::pair<unsigned int, khaos_event>)'**

How can I fix this? where do I make a misunderstanding? any comments and suggestions are appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: You should have gotten an error for `khoas_event` and `~khoas_event`. The class name is `khaos_event`.

Comment: maybe 1u, 1 is signed

Comment: `std::condition_variable` and `std::mutex` are not copyable or movable. You could have found this by creating a minimum reproducible sample: The code works if you delete the `m_cv` and `m_mtx` members, which suggests that they are the source of the problem. You can emplace a piecewise-constructed pair: `events.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(1), std::forward_as_tuple());`

Comment: Given that you just want a default-constructed `khaos_event`, at least to me it seems like `events[1]` is a bit simpler than `events.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(1), std::forward_as_tuple());`.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for root cause. Can I use the pointer like ```std::map<uint32_t, khaos_event*> events``` or it's not a good idea to wrap the m_cv and m_mtx? I am not familar with std::piecewise_construct/std::forward_as_tuple.

Comment: @hyperion007 You can edit your question to correct typos.

Comment: You can also do `events.try_emplace(1)`. If you use a pointer `std::map<uint32_t, khaos_event*>`, then you have to manage the lifetime of the `khaos_event` somehow, which is going to be very error-prone.

Comment: @RaymondChen, thanks for your advance. let me take some time to absorb them. or can use unique_ptr:). thanks for your help again.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that both the data members `m_cv` and `m_mtx` are **not copyable**(as their copy ctor is deleted). But the copy ctor is required when writing

```
events.insert(std::make_pair(1, khaos_event())); //copy ctor is required here
```

Here is another contrived example showing the same:

```
struct C
{
    C(const C&)=delete;
    C();
};       

class khaos_event
{
public:
  khaos_event(){};
  ~khaos_event(){}; 
 private:
     C c; //member variable
};

int main()
{
  std::map<uint32_t, khaos_event> events;
  events.insert(std::make_pair(1, khaos_event())); //copy ctor is required here   
}
```